# How to play video to Chromecast with subtitle?

Tags: subtitle, chromecast

I have an .mp4 file and an .srt file. How do I play video to Chromecast with subtitles?

[edited]

Applogize for the lack of information, 
i'm looking for iphone / ipad app for streaming to my chromecast

Comment: on what Mac? with what os x? what is not working?

Comment: @Buscar웃 i edited my question, sorry for my short question

Comment: thanks that will reduce the guessing :) so you are looking how to merge the srt with mp 4 on ios ?

Comment: i'm looking iphone app player support subtitle. maybe this is the best example : https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/avplayer/id395680819?mt=8

Answer (score 1):

The subtitle file cannot be loaded to play on the chromecast. If the video is already encoded with the subtitles then the Video will play with subtitles. I'm afraid Google needs to add support for playing `.srt` files along with the video files.